# Height on $\mathbb G^n_m$ and Néron–Tate heights

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, heights, diophantine-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and let $L$ be a line bundle on $A$. Then a Néron–Tate height $\hat h_L$ can be defined by taking a model $\mathcal A$ of $A$ (over the ring of integers of a field of definition of A) and a hermitian line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $\mathcal A$ that "extends" $L$. The definition of $\hat h_L$ then involves some arithmetic intersection theory on $\mathcal A$.

Now consider $A=\mathbb G^n_m(\mathbb{\overline Q}) $ (in this case $A$ is a group scheme). A very quick way of definining  “the” canonical height is the following:

$$
\hat h(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)=h(x_1)+\dotsb+ h(x_n)\quad (\ast)
$$

where $h$ is the usual Weil height on $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

> How are these two notions of height related? In particular what line bundle is hidden in the second "quick" definition?

Another obvious definition of height is by embedding $\mathbb G^n_m(\mathbb{\overline Q}) $ inside $\mathbb P^ {n}$ and then taking the restricted Weil height, but I suppose that in this case we don't have the nice properties of the Néron–Tate height.

**edit:** I suppose that $(\ast)$ is just  a renormalisation of the standard Weil height on $\mathbb P^n$ (i.e. they differ by O(1)) but there is the advantage that $\widehat h$ is $0$ only on (componentiwise) torsion points

Comment: Actually, the latter version is the one that's "canonical". The endomorphisms of $\mathbb G_m^n$ are the $d$th power maps, and the Weil height on projective space satisfy $h(P^d)=dh(P)$. You don't get a bilinear form in the $\mathbb G_m$ situation, but there is at least an inequality $h(P\cdot Q)\le h(P)+h(Q)$.